# Can anyone suggest a free equivalent of the Hoefler Text font?

Tags: fonts, typography

Can anyone suggest a free equivalent of the Hoefler Text font

[image]

On [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/find?similar=Hoefler%20Text&q=Go)

Comment: Free as in "doesn't cost anything" or free as in "I want to use @font-face on my website"?

Comment: If you have OSX, it comes free with the operating system.

Comment: It looks like Wikipedia changed its logo from Hoefler to Libertine, so I think I will try that. Very annoying that a font I have relied on from earliest Mac to my early-2011 machine is no longer available on High Sierra. I appreciate the designer making a living, but I cannot afford $299 for a license for a single computer.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming it's the general style you're looking to match, not exact characters, the key features of Hoefler are:

- The strong, curved serifs
- The quite-high contrast in stroke width
- A moderately high x-height and generally regal and precise shaping.

[Garamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garamond) is a font that has quite a lot of these features and might be a good stand-in. You probably have a version of it already, and there's also [a variant of it, **EB Garamond**, on Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/EB+Garamond), making it free and easy to use online in @font-face if needed.

It's got similar rounded serifs and similar contrast, but it's a bit more imprecise in the letter shapes, making it a bit less classically regal and imposing.

[image]

---

[Goudy Old Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goudy_Old_Style) is another classic old-style serif with similar properties and [a variant freely available to use on Google Web Fonts, **Sorts Mill Goudy**](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Sorts+Mill+Goudy). It's a bit sharper and more uniformly rounded than Garamond, which makes it a little closer to Hoefler, but it also has a few un-Hoefler-like flourishes (e.g. the spiky 'horn' on the lowercase g), and it's also a little lower in stroke contrast than Hoefler.

[image]

---

If you're more interested in the heavy 'classical' feel of Hoefler than the rounded serifs, [**Cardo**](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cardo) might be worth a look (also freely available on Google Web Fonts). It's very similar to Hoefler in the shape of the letters and in stroke contrast, and has a similarly serious schoolbook-y feel (it's designed for "classicists, Biblical scholars" amongst others). It's serifs are less rounded, but they're similarly heavy.

[image]

---

As a side note, if you're looking for a Hoefler-like font for the web, bare in mind that with an exact match, those very rounded serifs and details - particularly the bases of the descenders on characters like 'p' - probably won't render so well on a screen at small sizes.

Answer (score 0):

libertine is pretty good! Quality open type featured font

http://linuxlibertine.sourceforge.net/Libertine-EN.html

Comment: Hi strages, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer! Could you please include a screenshot of Libertine, so we can judge the similarity without going off-site? Thanks! If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!